# PostGIS Conversion Issues

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am having an issue using PostGIS (1.5.4) data.  It may be that I'm just not familiar enough with this technology to see the obvious (I'm a regular expert with nearly 4 hours of experience), but I am running into an error that I have been unable to solve with Google.

I have a table which includes Polygon data (and yes, I checked; the column type is geometry, not polygon- the Postgres native type).  The problem arises when I am trying to run a query on the table to find which shape contains a particular problem.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM geo_shape 
WHERE ST_Contains(geoshp_polygon, POINT(-97.4388046000, 38.1112251000));
```

The error I receive is 'ERROR:  function st_contains(geometry, point) does not exist'.  I tried using a CAST() function, but got 'ERROR:  cannot cast type geometry to polygon'.  I'm guessing the issue has to do with the way the data is stored- PGAdmin shows it as hex data.  I tried using `ST_GeomFromHEXEWKB()` just on a hunch, but received 'ERROR:  function st_geomfromhexewkb(geometry) does not exist'.

I'm fairly confused as to what the issue is here, so any ideas at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

st_contains needs a geom,geom as arguments...

Give this a try...

```
SELECT * FROM geo_shape 
WHERE ST_Contains(geoshp_polygon,
      GeomFromText('POINT(-97.4388046000 38.1112251000)'));
```

Editted to correct , issue in the point data.  ST_geomfromtext will work, kinda curious what the difference is there

Comment: Two problems: you mean `ST_GeomFromText`, and you have a parse error - invalid geometry.

Comment: This actually worked for me- the parse error was from the comma in the POINT data, and for some reason the function works with or without the ST_ in front.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix PostgreSQL's [geometric data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) with PostGIS's geometry type, which is why you see that error. I suggest using one of [PostGIS's geometry contstructors](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors) to help out:

```
SELECT * 
FROM geo_shape 
WHERE ST_Contains(geoshp_polygon,
                  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-97.4388046000, 38.1112251000),4326);
```

Or a really quick text way is to piece together the [well-known text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text):

```
SELECT 'SRID=4326;POINT(-97.4388046000 38.1112251000)'::geometry AS geom;
```

(this will output the WKB for the geometry type).

Comment: For some reason this keeps giving me an error stating 'Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs'.  Not sure if that's because the 'geometry_columns' table is incorrect or what.

Comment: This is a helpful error, since your spatial references (SRIDs) must match. Find the SRID of `geo_shape.geoshp_polygon` in either the `geometry_columns` table, or use [ST_SRID](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SRID.html) to directly query. If you need to transform from one spatial reference to another (e.g., WGS84 to NAD83 UTM10N), then use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).